# Property Selector and Where<T> Query using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to do that :

```
public class SomeEntityClass
{
    public Guid MyClassProperty {get;set;}
}

public class AnotherEntityClass
{
    public Guid AnotherProperty {get;set;}
}

public T GetByProperty<T>(Guid value, Expression<Func<T, object>> selector)
{
    return = Session.Query<T>().Where(x => selector == value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Should be called :

```
Repository.GetByProperty<SomeEntityClass>(Guid.NewGuid(), x => x.MyClassProperty );
Repository.GetByProperty<AnotherEntityClass>(Guid.NewGuid(), x => x.AnotherProperty);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `object` be `Guid` as you want a method that returns a `Guid`?

Comment: Why just not use `x=>x.MyClassId == Guid.NewGuid()` ?

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" isn't as helpful as saying what doesn't work (error message / example unexpected results).

Comment: @hazzik, i don't want to pass the predicate logic to the method. i only want to pass the property selector

Comment: As I can see you are using NHibernte there. why just not use `Session.Get<T>(id)` instead?

Comment: @George Duckett, actually, it doesn't build ! Since Where<T> takes an Expression<Func<T,bool>> as parameter

Comment: Something like `new EqualsExpression(idSelector, id)`

Comment: @hazzik, because the Id i want to use is not the real entityid. Maybe it's confusing, but forget the "ID" consideration. I want to pass a property selector to filter on it.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett, yep but what is the implementation of your EqualsExpression ? This is want i need to do actually.

Comment: Add an error message to your post.  Saying "it doesn't work" isn't sufficient for people to properly debug your problem.  Plus if you add the error message, people with the same question can search and find your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use something like that:

```
public T GetByProperty<T, TValue>(TValue value, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> selector) {
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), 
        selector.Parameters
    );

    return Session.Query<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: The signature of Equal is, Equal(Expression left, Expression right); so it doesn't work with "value" as the second parameter

Comment: Fixed to `Expression.Constant(value)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the selector on the object, so something like this should work

```
public T GetById<T>(Guid id, Func<T, object> idSelector)
{
    return Session.Query<T>().Where(x => idSelector(x) == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Also instead of the `Where`/`First(OrDefault)` combo, in similar situations, I usually use `Single(OrDefault)` because I like an exception to be thrown if there is a duplicate key somewhere.

Comment: To what kind of ORM is this connected? I've been using a similar pattern with EntityFramework (CodeFirst) and it works great.

Comment: to any ORM. Because it will be fall back to linq-to-objects

Comment: @Hazzik, you are right, I checked my implementation, and it uses Expresion<Func<>> not Func<>. Upvoted your answer. However, this approach works quite nice for linq-to-objects.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to SWeko's answer, an alternative allowing you to type the idSelector (to prevent comparisons of `Object` to `Guid`...)

```
public T GetById<T, TKey>(TKey id, Func<T, TKey> idSelector)  
{  
    return Session.Query<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => idSelector(x) == id);  
}
```

You'd call this with something like...

```
var result = GetById(guidId, (AnotherEntityClass x) => x.MyClassId);
```

More over, if you added the following class...

```
public class YetAnotherEntityClass
{
    public long MyId {get;set}
}
```

You can still use the same method...

```
var result = GetById(12345, (YetAnotherEntityClass x) x=> x.MyId;
```

---

If you're finding this does full table loads, consider the following:

```
public T GetFirstByCriterion<T, bool>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criterion)
{
    return Session.Query<T>().FirstOrDefault(criterion);
}
```

which can be called with

```
var result = GetFirstByCriterion((AnotherEntityClass x) x => x.AnotherProprty = guidId);
```

Comment: Fair one, error copied over from the OP and the expression wasn't compiled... Corrected