# How to avoid RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning in EF Core with complex LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Currently I have a LINQ statement that Entity Framework Core throws a warning: `System.InvalidOperationException: Warning as error exception for warning 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning': The LINQ expression '(Invoke(__selector_0, [x]).ToString() == __value_1)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.`

I have turned this 'throw warning as exception' in the database context initialization to enforce writing LINQ to evaluate on the server side.

```
public async Task<int?> ExistsAsync<TValue>(TestModel entity, Func<TestModel, TValue> selector)
{
    var value = selector(entity).ToString();

    var test = await _context.TestModel.Where(x => selector(x).ToString() == value).Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return test;
}
```

The above statement is used in the following way.

```
var id = await _service.ExistsAsync(new TestModel {Name = name}, x => x.Name);
```

Is there a way to get this to translate to TSQL and evaluate on the server side? Using `System.Linq.Expressions`?

---

Edit: Follow up question to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45040124/2679833) below, where is good resources for learning `System.Linq.Expressions`? I understand basic LINQ well but when it comes to building expression tree's, I don't know where to go.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Since your question was answered (by you) it is done.  Just accept the answer (you will need to wait a few days since you answered it yourself).  If you have additional questions, you will need to start a new question.  Do not ask subjective questions (like "best resource").  You should probably go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) again.

Comment: @Trisped I planned on accepting my answer as soon as StackOverflow will allow me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150425/2679833).

```
public async Task<int?> ExistsAsync<TValue>(TestModel entity, Expression<Func<TestModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var selector = expression.Compile();
    var value = selector(entity);

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Equipment, bool>>(Expression.Equal(expression.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), expression.Parameters);

    var id= await _context.TestModel.Where(predicate).Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return id;
}
```